# Matlab: for loop and sprintf combination

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I have the following data:

```
no_gridpoints = 640                                   % amount of columns in considered
surfaceelevation                                      % a 1x640 array with surface elevation
Terskol1752, Terskol1753, ... Terskol2017             % 365x1 arrays with daily mean temperatures for 1 year of which the fifth colomn contains the temperature data
```

I want to create temp_glacier files with the corresponding year in the file name. This with a loop over all the years (1752-2017) by using the sprintf command in the loop:

```
for k = 1752:2017
    for m = 1:no_gridpoints
    sprintf('temp_glacier%d(m)',k) = sprintf('Terskol%d(:,5)',k) + surfaceelevation
    end
end
```

However, I always get the error 'Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.'. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're mistaking `sprintf` for `eval`. The expression within `sprintf` is not evaluated, so your assignment is stating "Make this string = this other string added to an array" - it makes no sense. It would be far better practise for you to store your yearly data in a single cell array rather than  266 individually named variables, then you can easily manipulate them. I say better practise because if you to mean to use `eval`, you should know [it should be avoided](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7kmd5)!

Comment: The Comment by Wolfie is right. And it is difficult to know what you are really looking for. Do you want to create text files (comma separated for example) with the data? Or Matlab .mat files?? I get that you want a separate file for each year that contain the temperatures for that year. But what you what to do with the "+ surfaceelevation" part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment: it looks like you're mistaking `sprintf` for `eval`. The expression within `sprintf` is not evaluated, so your assignment is stating "make this string = this other string added to an array" - it makes no sense.

To correct your code as-is, you could do the following

```
for k = 1752:2017
    for m = 1:no_gridpoints
    eval(sprintf('temp_glacier%d(m) = Terskol%d(:,5) + surfaceelevation', k, k))
    end
end
```

**This is a bad idea**

It would be far better practise for you to store your yearly data in a single cell array (or because it's numerical and the same size, just a standard matrix) rather than 266 individually named variables. I say better practise because if you to mean to use `eval`, you should know [it should be avoided](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7kmd5)!

This method would look like the following:

```
Terskol = [ ... ] % your data here, in a 266*365 matrix where each row is a year
for k = (1752:2017) - 1751 % We actually want to loop through rows 1 to 266
    for m = 1:no_gridpoints
        % Your arrays were 1D, so you were originally getting a scalar temp val
        % We can do that here like so...
        temp_glacier(m) = Terskol(k, 5) + surfaceelevation; 
        % Now do something with temp_glacier, or there was no point in this loop!
        % ...
    end
end
```

Vectorising the inner loop:

```
for k = (1752:2017) - 1751 % We actually want to loop through rows 1 to 266
    temp_glacier = repmat( Terskol(k, 5) + surfaceelevation, 1, no_gridpoints );     
    % Do something with temp_glacier...
end
```